# How do I find by "ObjectId" mongodb's fields in django?

Tags: django, mongodb, objectid

I am finding method that get field by "ObjectId"

but, I was not find.

I decleared Entries model

```
class Entries(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False)
    content = models.TextField(null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)


@csrf_exempt
def viewPost(request, entry_number): # ex) entry_number = '513c780210ae920f58762d3d'
    e = Entries.objects.get(id = entry_number) # error!!
    return HttpResponse('zz')
```

it code raises error, therefore I tried to under codes.

```
e = Entries.objects.get(_id = entry_number) # error!!
e = Entries.objects.get(pk = entry_number) # error!!
e = Entries.objects.get(id = entry_number) # error!!
e = Entries.objects.get(_id = ObjectId(entry_number)) # error!!
e = Entries.objects.get(pk = ObjectId(entry_number)) # error!!
e = Entries.objects.get(id = ObjectId(entry_number)) # error!!
e = Entries.objects(id = entry_number) # error!!
```

its show me the messages

```
'invalid literal for int() with base 10: '513c780210ae920f58762d3d', ...
```

thus, now I am using pymongo(without django's ORM)

```
d = entries_table.find_one({'_id' : ObjectId(entry_number)})
return render_to_response('view.html', {'ROOT_URL':ROOT_URL,
                                        'entry':d, 'id':d['_id']})
```

somebody help me to use

Comment: you get that error because id only allow number (int). Have you seen your inputted value=513c780210ae920f58762d3d, it has letters

Comment: yes, i know that. but, i want to get by objectid

Comment: Ok I will try to search about objectId

Comment: try something like "Cookie.objects(id__exact = value)". It works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django ORM doesn't support MongoDB now. Use PyMongo instead.